# Android Device USB debugging

Tags: android, debugging, usb, adb

I plugged my phone(Samsung Galaxy S I9000) into my Ubuntu computer today, and noticed that my USB debugging didn't come up on my phone(I checked device settings are proper). I'm not sure what happened, I can't figure it out. My computer doesn't recognize my phone and my phone doesn't start running USB debugging. Its checked on my phone but maybe my drivers are screwed up somehow. I have also restarted it, issue adb commands but none helps. Same problem had come on my HTC device too but not know how to resolve it.

Anyone got any tips?

Comment: Does `# adb devices` list your phone(s)?

Comment: This did not deserve a downvote. I had exactly the same problem, and unfortunately the information given in the question is all you can find out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ubuntu follwing this steps can configure adb

http://esausilva.com/2010/05/13/setting-up-adbusb-drivers-for-android-devices-in-linux-ubuntu/

You probably didn't add  /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules.
I got same issue, and it works

for your samsung device add

```
#Samsung
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"
```

in the above file. more details check that URL

Comment: Can you tell me how to support two different devices(Samsung and HTC) at the same time. Do I need to add another line in that file with different SYSFS{idVendor} value for HTC ??? Thanks.

Comment: yes for htc add #HTC
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"