# How do I connect a Lenovo IdeaPad S6000 to Ubuntu and Android SDK

Tags: android, ubuntu, sdk, tablet

I have a Lenovo S6000 tablet running Android 4.2.1 and cannot connect from Android SDK in Ubuntu 12.04 Precise (adt bundle with eclipse). When I try to run my application the device appears but seems to be not recognized. Something like:

- Serial Number: ??????
- AVD Name: N/A
- Target: unknown
- Debug:
- State: ??

I already enabled the Developer Options menu and the USB debugging option in the tablet, clicking 7 times in `Settings -> About tablet -> Build number`

The command `adb devices` shows:

```
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
```

An `lsusb` throws that:

```
Bus 001 Device 036: ID 17ef:75e0 Lenovo
```

And `dmesg` shows:

```
[53099.904034] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 36 using ehci-pci
[53100.036973] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=17ef, idProduct=75e0
[53100.036979] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[53100.036983] usb 1-2: Product: IdeaTab S6000
[53100.036987] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: MediaTek
```

Any clue on how to start debugging an app?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Umm.. did you do the following: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html or search and find this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309110/android-device-usb-debugging

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thanks a lot. Finally add ``SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="17ef", MODE="0666"`` to the file ``/etc/udev/rules.d/70-android.rules``

Answer (score 0):

Go to Ubuntu software centre - install gMTP. connect the device.

It mount your device on Ubuntu.

for more details: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1790198.html